# Trying to build and run Apache Kafka 0.8 against Scala 2.9.2 without success

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

As stated in the topic description, I'm trying to get `Kafka 0.8` running with `Scala 2.9.2`.

I was able to get a working version using the quick start for `0.8` (https://cwiki.apache.org/KAFKA/kafka-08-quick-start.html), but it is compiled against `Scala 2.8.0` by default.

I tried to modify the step

```
./sbt package
```

to

```
./sbt "++2.9.2 package"
```

it compiles without errors but during start it complains that it cannot find the main class.

```
/tmp/kafka-8-test/kafka[0.8]$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh onfig/server1.properties
Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.Kafka
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the bin/kafka-server-start.sh script uses bin/kafka-run-class.sh to execute the generated jar file.

This script has hard-coded versions, so you need to customize it like this:

```
...
library=$(echo "$ivyPath/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.9.2.jar")
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$library

compiler=~$(echo "$ivyPath/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.9.2.jar")
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$compiler

log4j=$(echo "$ivyPath/log4j/log4j/jars/log4j-1.2.15.jar")
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$log4j

slf=$(echo "$ivyPath/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar")
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$slf

zookeeper=$(echo "$ivyPath/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/jars/zookeeper-3.3.4.jar")
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$zookeeper

jopt=$(echo "$ivyPath/net.sf.jopt-simple/jopt-simple/jars/jopt-simple-3.2.jar")
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$jopt

for file in $base_dir/core/target/scala-2.9.2/*.jar;
do
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
done

for file in $base_dir/core/lib/*.jar;
do
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
done

for file in $base_dir/perf/target/scala-2.9.2/kafka*.jar;
do
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
done
...
```

Answer (score 9):

`kafka-run-class.sh` is hard-coded to *Scala 2.8.0.* You can change 2.8.0 to 2.9.2 as suggested by prenomenon.

This works for me :

- Linux|Unix

  `sed -i "s/2.8.0/2.9.2/g" bin/kafka-run-class.sh`
- MacOS

  `sed -i.bak "s/2.8.0/2.9.2/g" bin/kafka-run-class.sh`

Comment: To build Kafka with Scala 2.9.2 I had to add the scala version to each build command, like `./sbt "++2.9.2 update"`
`./sbt "++2.9.2 package"`
`./sbt "++2.9.2 make-pom"`
`./sbt "++2.9.2 assembly-package-dependency"`

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version of Kafka 0.8.1.1 and gradlew the "SCALA_VERSION" is a variable in the script.

SCALA_VERSION=2.10.4

However, somewhere something goes wrong after:

```
./gradlew -PscalaVersion=2.10.4 jar

```

where one of the files does *not* have the 2.10.4 part, but only 2.10 :

`peter_v@trusty64:~/data/kafka/kafka-0.8.1.1-src$ find . -name '*.jar'
./perf/build/libs/kafka-perf_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar
./clients/build/libs/kafka-clients-0.8.1.1.jar
./system_test/migration_tool_testsuite/0.7/lib/kafka-perf-0.7.0.jar
./system_test/migration_tool_testsuite/0.7/lib/kafka-0.7.0.jar
./system_test/migration_tool_testsuite/0.7/lib/zkclient-0.1.jar
./examples/build/libs/kafka-examples-0.8.1.1.jar
./core/build/libs/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar ############   2.10 instead of 2.10.4 ?
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/zkclient-0.3.jar
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/log4j-1.2.15.jar
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/jopt-simple-3.2.jar
./core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar
./target/scala-2.10/kafka-0-8-1-1-src_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
./lib/apache-rat-0.8.jar
./contrib/hadoop-consumer/lib/piggybank.jar
./contrib/hadoop-consumer/build/libs/kafka-hadoop-consumer-0.8.1.1.jar
./contrib/hadoop-producer/lib/piggybank.jar
./contrib/hadoop-producer/build/libs/kafka-hadoop-producer-0.8.1.1.jar
./contrib/build/libs/contrib-0.8.1.1.jar
./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`

With a copy to the 2.10.4 name as a workaround, Kafka started correctly.

```

cp core/build/libs/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar core/build/libs/kafka_2.10.4-0.8.1.1.jar 
```